# SQL group by but order is important

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

is there any option to group by items but order of grouping is important?

Let's assume I have table with hardware and it's assigned to some users. And this hardware has some states like broken, ok, service. I want to group this table to have information, how long user had this item, but state is not important.

What I have:

```
+----+-------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | owner | state  | from       | to         |
+----+-------+--------+------------+------------+
| 1  | ow1   | ok     | 01.02.2019 | 04.06.2019 |
| 2  | ow1   | broken | 04.06.2019 | 12.06.2019 |
| 3  | srvc  | fixing | 12.06.2019 | 17.06.2019 |
| 4  | ow1   | ok     | 17.06.2019 | null       | -- null - still has
+----+-------+--------+------------+------------+
```

But I want to have:

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| owner | from       | to         |
+-------+------------+------------+
| ow1   | 01.02.2019 | 12.06.2019 | -- here we have min and max dates before state changed
| srvc  | 12.06.2019 | 17.06.2019 |
| ow1   | 17.06.2019 | null       | -- null - still has
+-------+------------+------------+
```

How to write query to achieve this result?

Comment: So for clarity - you want to know the contiguous periods (periods without gaps) of ownership?

Comment: 'here we have min and max dates before state changed' -  your question said ' state is not important.' did you mean 'here we have min and max dates before OWNER changed'

Comment: if the order is important how should ties (equal) values be handled..

Comment: I mean, that in result table I don't need to have state, but dates are important. So if user had an item and state had changed, it's not important is result table. But if owner was changed, it's important to have max date from 'to' column.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a gaps and islands problem. One solution is follows:

- Mark rows where owner changes (different from previous row) with a value 1
- Group all 1s and subsequent 0s together

I usually do this:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *
         , CASE WHEN owner = LAG(owner) OVER (PARTITION BY hardware_id ORDER BY [from]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chg
    FROM t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *
         , SUM(chg) OVER (PARTITION BY hardware_id ORDER BY [from]) AS grp
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT owner
     , hardware_id
     , grp
     , MIN([from])
     , MAX([to])
FROM cte2
GROUP BY owner, hardware_id, grp
```

I have assumed that you want separate results per every piece of hardware, remove the hardware column if that is not the case.

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=82f6289bbe61342b8c9fffdaaba3f50f)

Comment: @GordonLinoff  ... agreed that comment should/could have been more "subtle", to mine *"defence"* i wasn't totally awake jet at the time when i wrote that comment.. i am removing those comments..

Answer (score 1):

Try this below option with union all.

```
SELECT owner,from,to 
FROM your_table 
WHERE to IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT owner,MIN(from),MAX(to) 
FROM your_table
WHERE to IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY owner
```